# AesManaged Decryption in Metro WinRT application

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, windows-runtime

I have some text, encrypted by C#'s AesManaged, which must be decrypted in a WinRT Metro application. I cannot change the Encryption code, as the code has other dependencies which cant be changed.

The encryption function looks like this:

```
// Note: Edited out possibly real password and salt:
Guid password = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA");
Guid salt = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAAA-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-AAAAAAAAAAAA");

string EncryptedValue(string data)
{   
byte[] passwordBytes = password.ToByteArray();
byte[] saltBytes = salt.ToByteArray();

byte[] bKey = new byte[16];
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    bKey[i] = passwordBytes[i];
}

string encryptedData = String.Empty;
using (System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged aesAlg = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged())
{
    aesAlg.Key = bKey;
    aesAlg.IV = saltBytes;

    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    // Create the streams used for encryption.
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream csEncrypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {

                //Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(data);
            }

            encryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

return encryptedData;
}
```

Example data:

```
   // Decrypted value is: 2029
   var _id = EncryptedSettingsBase.Decrypt("ROSNJ1XnAozF7LC0wW8AOg==");
```

I read the following post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/7cfcc576-1c2c-4a50-a546-09a45d3ff41f
which looks like the same issue, however I haven't been able to get their suggestion to work, as I get the exception: 'Data error (cyclic redundancy check). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070017)'.

```
internal class EncryptedSettingsBase
{
    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        var passwordBytes = (new Guid("AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA")).ToByteArray();
        var salt = (new Guid("AAAAAAAAA-BBBB-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA")).ToString();

        byte[] bKey = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            bKey[i] = passwordBytes[i];
        }

        IBuffer pwBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(bKey);
        IBuffer saltBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(salt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16LE);
        IBuffer cipherBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(cipherText);

        // Derive key material for password size 32 bytes for AES256 algorithm
        KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider keyDerivationProvider = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("PBKDF2_SHA1");
        // using salt and 1000 iterations
        KeyDerivationParameters pbkdf2Parms = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(saltBuffer, 1000);

        // create a key based on original key and derivation parmaters
        CryptographicKey keyOriginal = keyDerivationProvider.CreateKey(pwBuffer);
        IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(keyOriginal, pbkdf2Parms, 32);
        CryptographicKey derivedPwKey = keyDerivationProvider.CreateKey(pwBuffer);

        // derive buffer to be used for encryption salt from derived password key 
        IBuffer saltMaterial = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(derivedPwKey, pbkdf2Parms, 16);

        // display the keys - because KeyDerivationProvider always gets cleared after each use, they are very similar unforunately
        string keyMaterialString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(keyMaterial);
        string saltMaterialString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(saltMaterial);

        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider symProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("AES_CBC_PKCS7");
        // create symmetric key from derived password material
        CryptographicKey symmKey = symProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);

        // encrypt data buffer using symmetric key and derived salt material
        IBuffer resultBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symmKey, cipherBuffer, saltMaterial);
        string result = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16LE, resultBuffer);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm probably doing something dumb, but I don't completely understand this stuff. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: If that is your real password and salt, posting it in a public place is not a good idea...

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago when trying to pair a JavaScript AES algorithm with a C# AES algorithm. I found that they are not all implemented the same, so I never got the results I expected!

Comment: I think for AES, your key needs to be 32 bytes, not 16.  Not sure if thats the issue, but I dont know what it will do if its too short.

Comment: @Eric - No worries, I changed them before posting ;-)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 AES supports both. AES-256 has a 32 byte key, and AES-128 a 16 byte key.

Comment: Just for the future: 1) A KDF is important for password based encryption 2) A constant is not a good IV or salt. You should create a new one for each encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code does the trick if I could change all my dependencies to encrypt properly:

Code here helped: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2966549-make-equal-aesmanaged-snippet-as-in-silverlight-an

Encryption code, C# 4.0 side:

```
string salt = "AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA";
string password = "AAAAAAAAA-BBBB-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA";

string EncryptedValue(string data)
{   
byte[] saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

string encryptedData = String.Empty;
using (System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged aes = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged())
{
    var rfc = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);

    aes.BlockSize = aes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize; 
    aes.KeySize = aes.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize; 
    aes.Key = rfc.GetBytes(32); 
    rfc.Reset(); 
    aes.IV = rfc.GetBytes(16);

    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    // Create the streams used for encryption.
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream csEncrypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                // Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(data);
            }

            encryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

return encryptedData;
}
```

Decryption code WinRT side:

```
protected string Decrypt(string encryptedData)
    {
        const string password = "AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA";
        const string salt = "AAAAAAAAA-BBBB-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA";

        IBuffer pwBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer saltBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(salt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer cipherBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(encryptedData);

        KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider keyDerivationProvider = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("PBKDF2_SHA1");

        KeyDerivationParameters pbkdf2Parms = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(saltBuffer, 1000);

        CryptographicKey keyOriginal = keyDerivationProvider.CreateKey(pwBuffer);
        IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(keyOriginal, pbkdf2Parms, 32);

        CryptographicKey derivedPwKey = keyDerivationProvider.CreateKey(pwBuffer);

        IBuffer saltMaterial = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(derivedPwKey, pbkdf2Parms, 16);

        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider symProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("AES_CBC_PKCS7");

        CryptographicKey symmKey = symProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);

        IBuffer resultBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symmKey, cipherBuffer, saltMaterial);

        byte[] asd;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(resultBuffer, out asd);
        string result = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, resultBuffer);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using PBKDF2 on one side and no PBKDF2 in the .net part. Unfortunately the part that you cannot change does not use the key correctly; it simply uses the UID directly.

Comment: Does that mean it can't work? How would you change the .Net side's key generation to fix it?

Comment: No, it can work, it's not cryptographically as secure as it should be. Remove the pbkdf2 on the WinRT side.