# Decrypt AES 128bit RijndaelManaged on WP8

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-8, cryptography

i'm having some trouble with this code.

```
var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, IV = iv, KeySize = 128, Key = keyBytes, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };

using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

The problem is here:

```
var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, IV = iv,
                                         KeySize = 128, Key = keyBytes,
                                         Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
```

Because even if i have included the `System.Security.Cryptography`, it doesn't find the `RijndaelManaed`. It says:

> " Namespace not found. Probably using or assembly reference "

In fact, when i add `using System.Security.Cryptography`, only options available are:

- Pkcs
- X509Certificates
- Xml

I need to use `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`

Comment: Try choosing a more descriptive title. "C# Help Windows 8 app project" is much too broad.

Answer (score 2):

It seems .NET for Windows Store Apps simply does not have `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`.

The [`Windows.Security.Cryptography` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx#classes) only has one class: `CryptographicBuffer`.

You'll have to use `SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm` to choose a symmetric encryption algorithm. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm%28v=win.10%29.aspx) you'll find a list of all the symmetric algorithms supporter on WinRT.

Comment: So in this case, how the code transform? I'm at the beginning of C# programming, so i'm not very practiced. I need an AES 128bit Decryptor algorithm

Comment: @Francesco See if this question help: [AesManaged Decryption in Metro WinRT application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11773851/857807). I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples on how to encrypt/decrypt using AES on WinRT.

Comment: Sorry man, i was wrong the title of the post. I mean Windows Phone 8, my mistake... Can you help me anyway?